# How to convert uint95 to bytes32 in solidity > 5.0?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

```
contract TypeConversion{

    uint96 data = 5;
    bytes32 b = bytes32(data);

}
```

It gives error:
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint96" to "bytes32".

What will be the better way to convert integers to a string in solidity?

Comment: What is `uint95`?

Comment: `What will be the better way to convert integers to a string in solidity?` - that is a different question than the question in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bytes32 b = bytes32(uint256(data));
```